# Process getting different environment variables to system settings

Tags: centos7, environment-variables, saltstack

I have an issue where a tomcat process started through salt stack is getting different environment variables than the ones set on the system. This is on a centos 7 server.

Below is the locale -v settings i get when i run the command on the server and then when i run the command through salt (salt executes the command as root)

```
locally run:
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

```
with salt:
   LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
    LC_CTYPE=C
    LC_NUMERIC=C
    LC_TIME=C
    LC_COLLATE=C
    LC_MONETARY=C
    LC_MESSAGES=C
    LC_PAPER=C
    LC_NAME=C
    LC_ADDRESS=C
    LC_TELEPHONE=C
    LC_MEASUREMENT=C
    LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
    LC_ALL=
```

So it seems salt is getting the wrong settings, when i look at the environ file for the salt process it has the correct environment variables.
I have even run a sleep 100 command through salt so i can view the environment variables for the spawned salt process but that too has the correct environment settings.
I have tried adding a locale.conf file with the correct settings but no different to salt.

Here is the locale.conf file:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

I can add in export lines to my tomcat config files to force the correct variables but thats a work around to the problem, i really need to find where salt gets its configuration to alter it.

Where else can i look to find where salt is getting these incorrect locale settings? I believe it is almost definitely a salt problem.

Comment: Maybe your *locally run* check skewed by executing it via openssh (which defaults to copying your workstations locale env over)? You might not be searching for the place where salt deviates from system defaults, but the place where you do.

Comment: In any case, [post](https://serverfault.com/posts/1037050/edit) the configuration files you *do* have on the server (`/etc/locale.conf`?)